# How to extract data from Tumblr API (JSON)?

Tags: json, api, get, tumblr

I have set up a Tumblr account and registered my application to authenticate it.

Tumblr Documentation: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2

I understand the API outputs JSON like this:

```
{
   "meta": {
      "status": 200,
      "msg": "OK"
   },
   "response": {
      "blog": {
         "title": "David's Log",
         "posts": 3456,
         "name": "david",
         "url": "http:\/\/david.tumblr.com\/",
         "updated": 1308953007,
         "description": "<p><strong>Mr. Karp<\/strong> is tall and skinny, with
            unflinching blue eyes a mop of brown hair.\r\n
         "ask": true,
         "ask_anon": false,
         "likes": 12345
      }
   }
}
```

Thats fine, but the documentation ends there. I have no idea how to get this information and display it on my site.

I thought the way you would get it would be something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myblog.tumblr.com/info?api-key=myapikey",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results){
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

But this does nothing.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Comment: There is nothing logged to your console? Seems to be working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MZR2Z/).

Comment: @Asad yes I get that too. But I am unsure as to how to actaully write items to the screen

Comment: are you using the request_token or the access_token?

Comment: @jdavid.net umm I have no idea. Is there a way to check?

Comment: @MeltingDog, actually for the above method you only need a valid API key.  the OAuth dance is required for User specific data.

Comment: @jdavid.net just checked the documentation. It says to use the OAuth as the API key

Comment: @MeltingDog, http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#blog-info , this shows that the authentication needed is just the **api key** or known as the **OAuth Consumer Key**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`results` is now the object you can use to reference the JSON structure. When you console.log the results object, it should appear in the Javascript developer console where you can explore the object tree.

### The response object

So when your success callback receives the response, the following should be available to you:

`results.meta.status` => 200

`results.meta.msg` => "OK"

`results.response.title` => "David's Log"

`results.response.posts` => 3456

`results.response.name` => "david"

`results.response.url` => "http://david.tumblr.com/"

`results.response.updated` => 1308953007

`results.response.description` => "`<p><strong>Mr. Karp</strong>..`"

`results.response.ask` => true

`results.response.ask_anon` => false

`results.response.likes` => 12345

---

### Writing to the page

If you actually want to see something written to your page you'll need to use a function that modifies the DOM such as document.write, or, since you're using Jquery,  $("#myDivId").html(results.response.title);

Try this:

- Add `<div id="myDivId"></div>` somewhere in the  of your page, and
- Add `$("#myDivId").html(results.response.title);` in your success callback function

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myblog.tumblr.com/info?api_key=myapikey",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results){
        // Logs to your javascript console.
        console.log(results); 
        // writes the title to a div with the Id "myDivId" (ie. <div id="myDivId"></div>)
        $("#myDivId").html(results.response.title); 
    }
});
```

Comment: Jut a note that api-key should be api_key in the URL string. :)

Comment: @LNA Whoops! Good catch =] Updated.

Comment: @Workman Is there a way to access the actual post data as well through this approach? As in to create a copy of the text within a post?

Comment: @Zeaklous Yeah! But it's a different resource (/posts instead of /info). Have a look at http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts, does that help?

Comment: Yes, I actually posted a question about the issue but my problem is solved now. Thanks though (:

Comment: @Zeaklous Good! This community is incredibly awesome. Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: This is a really bad example as it is missing so many things. For example the fact that if you are using jQuery, you will need to include the library before the script

Comment: @JGallardo Jquery example was from the original question. Please see OP.

Answer (score 1):

In the question code, the request type was not being set and it was being rejected by tumblr.  The jsonp error response was printing-out.  The code below correctly makes the jsonp request.

The key was specifying the type, and the dataType.  Good Luck happy hacking. ;-)

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/jdavidnet.tumblr.com/info",
    dataType:'jsonp',
    data: {
        api_key : "myapikey"
    },
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response, arguments);
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to write an object to the screen is to add an element containing its JSON representation to the page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/myblog.tumblr.com/info?api-key=myapikey",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(results){
        $("body").append(
            $("<pre/>").text(JSON.stringify(results, null, "    "))
        );
    }
});
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/MZR2Z/1/

Comment: Cool thats great! But how would I go about displaying say the Title from that within an HTML tag?