# Tumblr API - get JSON photo with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tumblr

I am trying to connect to tumblr API with angularJS

**EDIT**

I now I try to do:

JS:

```
tumblr.controller('tumblrs', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.tinymediaempire.tumblr.com/api/read/json/")
        .success(function(responses) {$scope.post = responses.response.posts;});
    });
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="tumblrs">       
    <ol>
        <li ng-repeat="spost in post">{{ spost.photos[0].alt_sizes[0].url }}</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Any console errors?

Comment: no erorrs, It just does not work, I do not know why

Comment: what json comes backs back as `response`?

Comment: for example https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/derekg.org/posts?id=7431599279&api_key=fuiKNFp9vQFvjLNvx4sUwti4Yb5yGutBN4Xh10LXZhhRKjWlV4

Comment: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#photo-posts

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON example I don't see a `.photo_url_500` property in the `photos` objects.

I think you need to refer to `.alt_sizes[1].url` to get the url for a 500px image.

You also need to use `ng-src` attribute instead of `src` as the `img` tag will try and load from the literal text before angular has loaded:

```
<img ng-src="{{ photo.alt_sizes[1].url }}" />
```

Comment: If you just put `{{ photo.alt_sizes[1].url }}` above the `img` tag, does it display a url as text?

Comment: it print {{ photo.alt_sizes[1].url }}

Comment: Sounds like your angular isn't working at all if it isn't parsing the bracket notation. post your module code as well as the controller, and post where you put your `ng-app` directive

Comment: `var tumblr = angular.module('tumblr', []);` `<html ng-app="tumblr">`

Comment: That looks ok, I don't understand why it wouldn't parse the bracket notation. Definitely no errors in Chrome dev tools console?

Comment: this is the erorr `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/NAME/posts/photo?api_key=KEY&notes_info=true. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: That's a CORS error - take a look at the question and answers on this post to see how to go about making a `jsonp` request instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367933/allow-my-tumblr-blogs-content-to-be-accessed-by-another-page