# Using an API for the first time with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, api, tumblr

My goal is to get the **first photograph of all tumblr posts**. I've recieved an authentication key, but unsure how to proceed further. I have a beginners understanding of JavaScript objects, but not how to implement them in this scenario. [Here is the Tumblr API documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2).

Tumblr use this as an example:

```
{
   "meta": {
      "status": 200,
      "msg": "OK"
   },
   "response": {
      "blog": {
         "title": "David's Log",
         "posts": 3456,
         "name": "david",
         "url": "http:\/\/david.tumblr.com\/",
         "updated": 1308953007,
         "description": "<p><strong>Mr. Karp<\/strong> is tall and skinny, with
            unflinching blue eyes a mop of brown hair.\r\n
            He speaks incredibly fast and in complete paragraphs.</p>",
         "ask": true,
         "ask_anon": false,
         "likes": 12345
      }
   }
}
```

However, I assume this is the object's output.

My ultimate goal is to post an image in a simple `div`:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="json-container">
      JSON image goes here!
   </div>
</div>
```

Any help or links to beginners references would be great.

Comment: Seems to be very close to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14514522/how-to-extract-data-from-tumblr-api-json?rq=1

Comment: You should delete this. StackOverflow frowns on asking multiple questions on the same thing, back to back.